# Detect treadle press

Tags: pressure

I need to detect if a foot treadle has been pressed and send a signal to a Microcontroller unit notifying of that press. What is the best method to achieve this? What kind of sensor can be used and how? I thought of a push button being placed under the treadle, would this work?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Hall effect? How much movement needs to be detected? Microswitch?

Comment: Um, how about a [pedal switch](https://www.speedwaymotors.com/Speedway-Universal-Mechanical-Brake-Pedal-Light-Switch,1972.html?sku=91031306&utm_medium=CSEGoogle&utm_source=CSE&utm_campaign=CSEGOOGLE&gclid=CjwKCAjw2Jb7BRBHEiwAXTR4jUzfA5Ko_GpUq3fjjeZV12l0Tod-2A6tRnlZoxKX4t88CSmF_pMwyBoCDc0QAvD_BwE)?

Answer (score 1):

Purchase a proper footswitch unit. You need to decide your specifications:

- Momentary action or latched.
- Normally open (NO), normally closed (NC) or changeover. The latter gives you options.

Program your microcontroller with a pull-up on the input. Wire your switch from the input to ground so that it pulls low when pressed.

You might need to debounce your microcontroller input either in hardware or in software. There are thousands of articles on how to do this and a web search should quickly give you a suitable approach.